# More advanced search operators

Tags: feature-request, search

How do I search for [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) and/or [php](/questions/tagged/php)?

I know I can search for both: `[azure] [php]` but I want to search for `([azure]+[php])|[azure]`, that is, general questions only tagged with [azure](/questions/tagged/azure), along with questions that are tagged with both [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) and another language.

Comment: I realize this is a silly quesiton. I wanted to "weight" the PHP ones more to the top. Like, if you wanted to talk about [heroku] in general but you really cared the MOST about [heroku][rails]. Perhaps a Sort the results thing?

Comment: It looks like elasticsearch does have the ability to do the boosting using the ^ but I couldn't get it to work here so it has likely been disabled in some way... or maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `/questions/tagged/` url, like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure+php+or+azure
```

Comment: That URL doesn't seem to weight PHP questions at the top as the OP requested.